# I got an error after running my first Selenium test in Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for E:\i_Chile_Okeno Profile\i_Software Tester\Softwarez\Selenium Installations\new jars\selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module
```

I created another Java project, and when building the path, this time I chose Classpath and not Modulepath. I copypasted the code ?(changed the class name to Day2) and still got the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at seleniumtest2/net.serenestudy.selenium.webdriver.basic.Day2.main(Day2.java:30)
```

```java
package net.serenestudy.selenium.webdriver.basic;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Day2 {

    WebDriver driver;

    public void invokeBrowser() {


            try {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\i_Chile_Okeno Profile\\i_Software Tester\\Softwarez\\Selenium Installations\\new jars\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                driver.get("http://serenestudy.net");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Day2 myObj = new Day2();
        myObj.invokeBrowser();

    }

}
```

Comment: Selenium-java project setup is well explained here, I think this may help you: https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/configure-eclipse-with-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 2):

This error is probably because you are trying a space between folder name so it causes the problem.
Try the same without a space!

Comment: Hi Vishvas, I tried removing all the spaces when naming my folders but I still got another error - " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at seleniumtest2/net.serenestudy.selenium.webdriver.basic.Day2.main(Day2.java:30)"

Comment: Have you added all the necessary dependencies to run your project? I will suggest you to use Maven or Gradle for the same as they will install all the required dependency JAR files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I researched about Maven and found out its an excellent way to import all the required JAR files. However, I have realized that the problem was that I installed Eclipse IDE for Java EE and this was creating the problem. After installing IDE for Java developers, the code worked without any problems. Please tell me, can Eclipse IDE for Java EE be used to run test scripts? And if so, can you provide links to how it works.

Comment: I basically use That with Eclipse IDE. I am also surprised why it is not working in your case! Selenium in Eclipse IDE with Maven or Gradle is perfect.

Comment: Which Eclipse IDE do you use?... In the latest version, you have to select different options to install, first I chose "Eclipse IDE for Java EE" and it didn't work with my test scripts, then I installed another option "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" and it worked perfectly.

Comment: both Eclipse IDEs now work without problems with my test scripts. Thanks for guiding me.